# What is the most efficient way to do this process in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, anonymous-function, jquery-events

This works flawlessly, but somehow I think there are easier and quicker ways to do this. I'm unsure, and I'm looking for suggestions. Here's the code:

```
    /* create a hover event and a click event */
// set the status of whether the box is open or closed
var status = 0;

// remove the css hover state (fall back hover)
$("#testApp").off("hover");

// add a jQuery mouseover and mouseout event
$("#testApp").on("mouseover", function() {
    $("#testApp div").css({
        "background-image":"url(./images/svg/menucorner-bg-lit.svg)"
    });
});

$("#testApp").on("mouseout", function() {
    $("#testApp div").css({
        "background-image":"url(./images/svg/menucorner-bg.svg)"
    });
});

// create a click event
$("#testApp").on("click", function() {
    if(status == 0) {
        // remove the mouseover and mouseout event when the div opens
        $("#testApp").off("mouseover");
        $("#testApp").off("mouseout");
        $("#testApp div").css({
            "background-image":"url(./images/svg/menucorner-bg-lit.svg)",
            "height":"200px",
            "background-color":"#ccc"
        });
        return status = 1;
    }else{
        // add the mouseover and mouseout event when the div closes
        $("#testApp").on("mouseover", function() {
            $("#testApp div").css({
                "background-image":"url(./images/svg/menucorner-bg-lit.svg)"
            });
        });

        $("#testApp").on("mouseout", function() {
            $("#testApp div").css({
                "background-image":"url(./images/svg/menucorner-bg.svg)"
            });
        });
        $("#testApp div").css({
            "height":"50px",
            "background-color":"transparent"
        });
        return status = 0;
    }
});
```

So basically it creates a hover state and a click toggle. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Storing and reusing the result of each query that is performed more than once would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1 jQuery Object to rule them all

Since you use `$("#testApp");` at the top of the function you could set it as a variable

```
var testAppEl = $("#testApp")
```

Then use that instead of creating a new jQuery object everytime

### Use `hover`

You could put this block:

```
// add a jQuery mouseover and mouseout event
$("#testApp").on("mouseover", function() {  
$("#testApp").on("mouseout", function() {
```

Into a `.hover()`:

```
testAppEl.hover(function() {
    $(this).css({
        "background-image":"url(./images/svg/menucorner-bg-lit.svg)"
    });
}, function() {
    $("#testApp div").css({
        "background-image":"url(./images/svg/menucorner-bg.svg)"
    });
});
```

### Combine `off()`

These two right here can be mixed

```
// Old
$("#testApp").off("mouseover");
$("#testApp").off("mouseout");

// New
testAppEl.off("mouseover mouseout");
```

### Use CSS in a better way

As Drew suggested, add classes in a CSS file instead of dynamic, hard to track CSS through jQuery i.e.:

```
.someCSS {
    background-image: url(./images/svg/menucorner-bg-lit.svg);
    height: 200px;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
```

Then in your jQuery use

```
testAppEl.addClass("someCSS");
```

### Strict Type/Value Comparison

Also, for your first `if` block, you should really be using the strict comparison operator:

```
if (status === 0) {
```

Comment: Also to add to this, consider using `CSS classes` as replacement for your `.css()` it's easier to maintain and much more easier to read IMO.

Comment: @Drew, added it. Good point

Comment: That's fantastic!!! Thank you so much. We're learning jQuery in school, but they neglect to teach best practices or efficiency. The issue is the pace the class can progress at I guess.

Comment: @ShaunCameronMcKinnon Hey no problem. Just remember, jQuery has [EXCELLENT docs](http://api.jquery.com) and has the largest community of any JS library ever. If you are ever unsure of the efficiency of a method, check the docs first and then lurk in the [forums](http://forum.jquery.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can fusion your two mouseover mouseout handlers into one:

```
$("#testApp").on("mouseover mouseout", function(e) {
    img = e.type == 'mouseover' ? 'menucorner-bg-lit.svg' : 'menucorner-bg.svg';
    $('div', this).css({
        "background-image":"url(./images/svg/"+img+")"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

And lastly chain and refactor

```
function addHover(){
      // add the mouseover and mouseout event when the div closes
        $("#testApp").on("mouseover", function() {
            $("#testApp div").css({
                "background-image":"url(./images/svg/menucorner-bg-lit.svg)"
            });
        })
        .on("mouseout", function() {
            $("#testApp div").css({
                "background-image":"url(./images/svg/menucorner-bg.svg)"
            });
        });

}

/* create a hover event and a click event */
// set the status of whether the box is open or closed
var status = 0;

// remove the css hover state (fall back hover)
$("#testApp").off("hover")
// create a click event
.on("click", function() {
    if(status == 0) {
        // remove the mouseover and mouseout event when the div opens
        $("#testApp").off("mouseover");
        $("#testApp").off("mouseout");
        $("#testApp div").css({
            "background-image":"url(./images/svg/menucorner-bg-lit.svg)",
            "height":"200px",
            "background-color":"#ccc"
        });
        return status = 1;
    }else{
        addHover();
        $("#testApp div").css({
            "height":"50px",
            "background-color":"transparent"
        });
        return status = 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can suggest is to declare differenct css classes and instead of changing the CSS by calling $.css() use toggleClass or addClass / removeClass

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding and removing event handlers, you can attach [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to the element to enable and disable the hover events.

```
// add a jQuery mouseover and mouseout event
$("#testApp").on("mouseover", function() {
    if (!$(this).data("disabled")) {
        $("#testApp div").css({
            "background-image":"url(./images/svg/menucorner-bg-lit.svg)"
        });
    }
}).on("mouseout", function() {
    if (!$(this).data("disabled")) {
        $("#testApp div").css({
            "background-image":"url(./images/svg/menucorner-bg.svg)"
        });
    }
}).on("click", function() {
    if (!$(this).data("disabled")) {
        $("#testApp div").css({
            "background-image":"url(./images/svg/menucorner-bg-lit.svg)",
            "height":"200px",
            "background-color":"#ccc"
        });
        $(this).data("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $("#testApp div").css({
            "height":"50px",
            "background-color":"transparent"
        });
        $(this).data("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

And as others have said, using [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) instead of [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) will help to keep behaviour and appearance as separate concerns.